# i3 same workspace on two displays

Tags: i3, regolith

Can `i3` (I'm using regolith actually) show the same workspace on two different displays?

I use `jupyter notebook` for teaching and I would somehow like to solve that my students only see the "active" notebook, but I can switch between my notes (usually other notebooks) and the notebook I'm showing them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [workspace](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#workspace_screen) command you can assign a workspace to multiple screens.

```
workspace <workspace> output <output1> [output2]…
```

Here are some examples:

```
workspace 1 output LVDS1
workspace 2 output primary
workspace 5 output VGA1 LVDS1
workspace "2: vim" output VGA1
```

Comment: Based on the documentation ("You can specify multiple outputs. The first available will be used.") this will not have the effect of having workspace X show on two outputs, which I am looking for. Or alternatively, showing the same window on multiple workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way of achieving this in Regolith is mirroring the external display via the gnome control center.